# Array placement new in combination with _aligned_malloc, what's the proper way to delete?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-alignment, placement-new

Started experimenting with placement `new` and `delete` along with memory alignment and it feels like being brainy smurf in papas smurf's lab.

Lets say I have an object e.g.,

```
struct obj {
...
};
```

and I want to allocate in aligned storage an array with `N` such objects. What I do is:

```
obj *buf = new (static_cast<obj*>(_aligned_malloc(sizeof(obj) * N, 64))) obj[N];
```

That is, I use placement new in combination with `_aligned_malloc`.

### Q

- Is this way of allocating aligned storage proper?
- Is it OK (probably not) to use `delete []` to deallocate afterwards or I need some special handling?

P.S
I know that `_aligned_malloc` is not standard but rather MVSC specific.

Comment: Wouldn't explicite destructor call be more appropriate? I mean something like `buf->~obj()` and then function to free memory?

Comment: @W.F. I have a hinch that I must do something like you're suggesting and then call `_aligned_free`.

Comment: On a side note: Is the `static_cast<obj*>` really necessary here? AFAIK placement new takes a `void*` as parameter.

Comment: You don't need the static_cast

Comment: @tehcnically array placement new is unusable because it may require unspecified bookkeeping overhead which you didn't allow for in your malloc. The "correct" way is to loop N times calling non-array placement new each time

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it sufficient for your task to use C++11 [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)?

For the question regarding `delete[]` - `aligned_malloc`ed memory should be freed using `_aligned_free`. Of course you need to call destructor first. [Look this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098638/7574136)

**EDIT:**

```
#include <malloc.h>

__declspec(align(64))
struct obj
{
    int i;
    char c;

    obj() : i{ 1 }, c{ 'a' } {}

    void* operator new[](size_t n)
    {
        return _aligned_malloc(n, 64);
    }

    void operator delete[](void* p)
    {
        _aligned_free(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    obj *buf = new obj[N];

    buf[2].i = 1;

    delete[] buf;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine it creates properly aligned storage, c-tors and d-tors are called because of `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of manual malloc/free.

Comment: Stupid enough, I'd like to contain my features to pre C++11. U see manager's opinion counts for 20 votes.

Comment: @101010 second edit with what I believe is the correct way of doing this

Comment: @101010 - In my experience, manager's decisions count for a *lot* more than 20 votes.  Changing compiler version is a non-trivial business risk, and if you have to support old versions of AIX/HPUX (spit!) You may not have the choice.